# npm error 'prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command'?

Tags: npm

While I am running npm command this error was showing:

> 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

How can I rectify it?

Comment: what is the command that you ran

Comment: I just put **npm -v** command

Comment: doesn't it showed the version

Comment: It is showing version along with this error. But when i try to install packages it doesn't install

Comment: I think you should install node again because maybe there can be crashed files

Comment: I tried multiple times but the same error occurs

Comment: have you installed node in the default location

Comment: yes on the default location